# Is Java default access modifier used for top level class definition in practice?

Tags: java

In my rather limited experience, I have not across DEFAULT(i.e.no modifier) access modifier being used for top level Class definition at my job projects. Is it a good practice to use DEFAULT access modifier(where ever applicable) Or is public class with access control on variable and method level a better approach?

Comment: It is good practice to make visibility as limited as possible. If you've got a top level class which doesn't need to be visible outside the package - make it package protected (i.e. default).

Comment: Default access for top-level class is definitely(!) good practice.

Comment: If you want a practical example, lots of the top-level classes in Guava are package protected: they are implementation details which aren't part of the public API, e.g. [`RegularImmutableList`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/RegularImmutableList.java).

Comment: Thank you Andy, Andreas.  Tunaki - This question is indeed a duplicate!